# Is it possible to remove the Community Wiki status of a question?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I noticed [my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/how-to-market-yourself-as-a-software-developer) was automatically updated to Community Wiki after 15 answers, and that prevents me from  enjoying the upvotes.

Is it possible to remove this status?

**Note**: the question only had that many answers because I've set a bounty for it 3 times already. And as you know, bounties tend to get people's attention...

Comment: This seems more like an attempt to rep farm rather than provide benefit for the community

Comment: This is an attempt to get useful info to help me improve my software engineer *persona*, while collecting a little bit of rep in the process. I won't lie, these 2 reasons are incredibly selfish, but you guys are invited to tag along.

Comment: @Ryathal I'm sure if we did some calcs together we would see that I stopped earning points after 15 upvotes (75 rep), which is when the question became Community Wiki. Since then I offered a total of 200 rep points to get better answers. In other words, I gave much more rep than I received trying to get high quality answers. Yesterday I still opened a bounty on another answer of HLGEM to award him for his great answer on my question, which got selected as the new official answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to remove the community wiki status of a question.

**However**, it is a very rare thing to do. I've done it in the past when someone has made too many edits to their own question or they've been the "victim" of several other users making essentially duplicate edits in a short period of time.

As for your question:

With more than 15 answers (20 in this case) posted, this question is tending to the "not constructive" and the CW threshold on the number of answers is designed to reflect this.

Questions with many answers are an indication that they are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange question and answer model where there is supposed to be a few "correct" answers provided.

If you are getting many answers then this is a sign that the question is inviting discussion and debate. If you check the "not constructive" close reason you will see:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

I'm not saying that this **is** true of your question, but it is generally true. If we change the threshold then potentially more bad questions will be left on the site.

*In my opinion the CW threshold on other sites is too high - it should be 15 answers network wide (except for perhaps Code Golf).*

Comment: I'm getting many answers because it's the 3rd time I set a bounty on it, plain and simple.

Comment: And the question remains: is it possible to remove the Community Wiki status of a question?

Comment: @karlphillip - see my update

Comment: Well, if the flag is not going to be removed then I would like the bounty to be removed and those points be restored to my reputation, because I'm not that altruist! I'm yet to find a question on Programmers that has had that many bounties set for it. And people still ask why that question had so many answers...