# Please Close This Question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-close

Please close [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28579/1996) ASAP.

I'm not sure if I've ever seen a non-spam question that was more off-topic.

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: @YannisRizos Can't VTC when there's a bounty up.

Comment: @AnnaLear That I didn't know, thanks...

Comment: I can award the bounty in 5 hours, then you guys are welcome to close it.

Comment: That said, I agree with closing this question 100%. It's entirely off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little background on the bounty:

Earlier today I closed the question referenced in [this Meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-community-wiki-status-of-a-question), which is the same question @karlphillip mentions on his bounty. He felt he should award one last bounty to one of the answerers, but as the question was closed [I advised him to find another one of the answerer's answers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3988916#3988916), on an open question, and award the bounty there. Didn't really want to re-open the original question for 24 hours, as we both agreed on the closure.

Obviously that failed miserably since he chose an even more close worthy question to set the bounty on ;P That's on me, I should have mentioned that he should find a good on topic question as I'm painfully aware that there are still a lot of open questions that don't belong to the site. Apologies for that.

Back to the question in question:

I agree that it's off topic and the proper way to handle this would be to refund the bounty and close the question. If no one objects though, I'd prefer to wait for 5 hours for @karlphillip to award the bounty and then close it.

---

Closed.

Comment: And of course the damn bot tweeted it. This is a bigger mess than I thought.

Comment: If it should be closed, it should be closed: waiting for the bounty to be awarded due to an unrelated closure doesn't make very much sense, especially since the bounty isn't even for action done on the question it was placed. Rewarding a user by placing a bounty on unrelated questions that they answered goes against the spirit of SE, where answers—not users—are king.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The bounty was awarded, you guys can close the question now.

Comment: Yannis - closing "humility" question means `status-completed` for this [Meta question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3370/please-close-this-question) doesn't it?

Comment: @gnat yes, it does ;)